# How to run this login program successfully?

Tags: webdriver

```
import java.io.File;


public class LoginPage { 


private final WebDriver driver;  

  public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {    

        this.driver = driver;  } 



public void loginAs(String username, String password) {  

 DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
```

ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);

// WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);

driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=uk");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(username);

driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password);

driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();ogin.loginAs("username", "password");}}

```
 }  

 public static void main(String[] args){
```

File file = new File("C:/Users/E20039504/Desktop/Selenium Jar/IEDriverServer.exe");

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

LoginPage login = new LoginPage(new InternetExplorerDriver());

```
login.loginAs("username", "password"); 
   }
 }
```

I am trying to login to a Salesforce application but this code snipet of mine is not working.Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

The Id of the password text input is "password" and not "pwd".
To press to Login button, you should also use its Id, which is "Login"

Comment: +1, or if you really needed to use it's class name, the correct one is `loginButton` not `Login_Button`

Answer (score 0):

Used `password` instead of `pwd` and `login` instead of `login_button`

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys(password);   

 driver.findElement(By.className("Login_button")).click();
```

This code is work for me correctly

```
      public class login 
         {
public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
           ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
             WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);          
             driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=uk");

             try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
             driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("username");   
                     driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");   
                     driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();   

}
      }
```

Comment: Unable to find element with id == username (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 281 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:09:54'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_29'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Session ID: 1067a8ce-613e-45d6-a8cf-bc441b2415f6
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: Is it that the IE8 does not detect the object properties when run via Webdriver. Using the Dev tool , I could find the Id, name which actually helps in differentiating the object properties. Kindly advise.

Comment: @user1776382 - Please check my edit answer. let me know what happen, this code is working for me in IE8 browser

Comment: Thanks Ankit for ur reply but unfortunately, its still throwing me the same error message:Unable to find element with id == username (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 265 milliseconds

Comment: As per my solution I am not getting error, it work correct,please can you show me your updated code ?

Comment: HI Ankit, I have pasted the entire code in my program section again. Kindly help. I have commented // WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities); and have tried with making it active also.

Comment: I paste my code use this code and let me know it was working or not for you.

Comment: I am bugged with the same error message again and again. I tried ur exact piece of code and following is the error message:Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == username (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 254 milliseconds